# extract data from url with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, data-extraction, bigdata

I want to get ( word - explanation) data from a dictionary site with jquery and write it to csv file. Every word has a page, i can extract data from page but data is spread trough urls (/dct/a/1   ..dct/b/2). How should i extract them through urls at once and write them as one line for each ?

```
$('#name').text();
$('.explanation').text();
```

Comment: Might be useful to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript

Comment: no ,thats not what i mean.web site has alot urls, for each word there is an url a,b,c,d that make 30 different url i know them they are visible i just want to search within them .For each word there are list of keywords a letter has 200 word ,each word has a page.i need that pages data but thousands of them cant be done manually.

Comment: Then use ajax? I guess, since you marked your question as jquery it has to be done client side?